# Dual Axis Google chart showing incorrect scale

Tags: reactjs, graph, google-visualization, react-google-charts

I'm trying to build a dual axis google chart using **Combo Chart**. On one side the Y axis scales correctly as per values but not the other one.

Refer the image:
[Sample chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1VnZH.png)

and my Sample data:

```
[
    [ "year", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F" ],
    [ "2019", 100, 0, 300, 0.0365, 0, 0.1095 ],
    [ "2020", 100, 0, 300, 0.073, 0, 0.219 ]
    
.....
]
```

As you can see the Chart, data point 300 ('C') is shown at 400 in left side Y axis. and data point 0 ('B') is shown at 100.

Whereas the right side Y axis (D,E,F) shows data correctly on scale.

Any idea what's causing this scaling issue?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the chart was stacked. isStacked: false in options solved the issue.